# Parse and Facebook login and signup returning "User Cancelled Login" (iOS 8.1 + Swift 1.2)

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I've been attempting to use Parse (version 1.7.4) to login and sign up users with Facebook's SDK (version 4.1), but every time I attempt to signup, the following code prints "User cancelled FB login", which means the user is being returned as nil, but there isn't an error. I don't know if this is a Parse issue or a Facebook issue, but if anyone has any idea how to possibly solve this issue, I will be immensely grateful.

This is the code for my Login/Signup View Controller:

```
let permissions = [ "email","user_birthday", "public_profile", "user_friends"]

@IBOutlet weak var lblStatus: UILabel!

@IBAction func facebookLoginDidPress(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.lblStatus.alpha = 0

    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(self.permissions, block: {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if user == nil {
            if error == nil {
                println("User cancelled FB login")
                self.lblStatus.text = "User cancelled login"
                self.lblStatus.alpha = 1
            }else if error != nil {
                println("FB login error: \(error)")
                self.lblStatus.text = "Error: \(error)"
                self.lblStatus.alpha = 1
            }
        } else {
            if user!.isNew {
                println("User signed up and logged in with Facebook! \(user)")
                self.requestFacebook()
                self.returnUserData()
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("signedUp", sender: self)
            } else {
                println("User logged in via Facebook \(user)")
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loggedIn", sender: self)
            }
            if self.delegate != nil {
                self.delegate!.onFacebookLogin(self)
            }
        }
    })

}

func requestFacebook() {

    let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

        if ((error) != nil)
        {
            // Process error
            println("Error: \(error)")
        }
        else if error == nil
        {

            var userData: NSDictionary = NSDictionary(objectsAndKeys: result)

            /*
            if let facebookID : NSString = result.valueForKey("id") as? NSString {
                println("User FbId is: \(facebookID)")
            } else {println("No facebookID fetched")}

            if let name : NSString = result.valueForKey("first_name") as? NSString {
                println("User's Name is: \(name)")
            } else {println("No name fetched")}

            if let gender : NSString = result.valueForKey("gender") as? NSString {
                println("User's gender is: \(gender)")
            } else {println("No gender fetched")}

            if let name : NSString = result.valueForKey("first_name") as? NSString {
                println("User's Name is: \(name)")
            } else {println("No name fetched")}

            if let birthday : NSString = result.valueForKey("birthday") as? NSString {
                println("User's birthday is: \(birthday)")
            } else {println("No birthday fetched")}
            */

            var facebookID: AnyObject? = userData["id"]
            PFUser.currentUser()!.setObject(facebookID!, forKey: "fbid")

            var name: AnyObject? = userData["first_name"]
            PFUser.currentUser()!.setObject(name!, forKey: "username")

            var gender: AnyObject? = userData["gender"]
            PFUser.currentUser()!.setObject(gender!, forKey: "gender")

            var birthday: AnyObject? = userData["birthday"]
            PFUser.currentUser()!.setObject(birthday!, forKey: "birthday")

            var pictureURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/\(facebookID)/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1"

            var URLRequest = NSURL(string: pictureURL)
            var URLRequestNeeded = NSURLRequest(URL: URLRequest!)


            NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(URLRequestNeeded, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!,data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    var picture = PFFile(data: data)
                    PFUser.currentUser()!.setObject(picture, forKey: "picture")
                    PFUser.currentUser()!.saveInBackground()
                }
                else {
                    println("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            })
        }
    })
}

func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
    println("User Logged Out")
}

func returnUserData()
{
    let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
        if ((error) != nil)
        {
            // Process error
            println("Error: \(error)")
        }
        else
        {
            if let userName : NSString = result.valueForKey("name") as? NSString {
                println("User Name is: \(userName)")

            } else {println("No username fetched")}

            if let userEmail : NSString = result.valueForKey("email") as? NSString {
                println("User Email is: \(userEmail)")
            } else  {println("No email address fetched")}

            if let userGender : NSString = result.valueForKey("gender") as? NSString {
                println("User Gender is: \(userGender)")
            } else {println("No gender fetched") }
        }
    })
}
```

Here's the code from my AppDelegate.swift (with the Parse keys edited out of course):

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Parse
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    //Parse Configuration
    Parse.setApplicationId("XXXXXXX", clientKey: "XXXXXXX")

    PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptionsInBackground(launchOptions, block: nil)

    PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)

    //Facebook Configuration
    FBSDKLoginButton()

    PFUser.enableRevocableSessionInBackground()

    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    self.saveContext()
}

func application(application: UIApplication, url: NSURL, sourceApplication: NSString, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {

    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
        application,
        openURL: url,
        sourceApplication: sourceApplication as String,
        annotation: annotation)

}
```

And here are screenshots of my frameworks:

[image: Frameworks as seen on side bar]

[image: Frameworks as seen on Link Binaries section]

I double checked my info.plist and made sure my bundle identifier was in my Facebook app settings and my facebook information was in my Parse app settings. I tried making a completely new Parse and Facebook app and the issue persists. I remember testing the Facebook login and Parse user signup separately months ago and a user was created and the account was linked to the app, but after implementing PFFacebokUtils and deleting the old user, the login seems to continue to state that the user "Cancelled FB login." Could the app be saving or caching the old user or some facebook token that I'm not aware of that's preventing another login or signup? I tried using the PFUser.logOut() and printed the information to confirm that there was no existing user in my app, but it still says that the user cancelled the login. Would using an accessToken fix things? Would getting my Facebook app approved change anything? If anyone knows the answers to any of these questions or has an idea that hasn't been brought up in previous answers or comments, please let me know. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: What makes you think that the problem is in requestFacebook() or returnUserData() ? Are you seeing "User signed up and logged in with Facebook!" in the console? If not, then the code never gets to this section of the code. I can't see the error in your code, unfortunately, though I'd recommend you'd trim it back to the bare minimum to help diagnose the problem. In fact, I'd recommend you temporarily cut everything except permissions, and copy paste the Parse suggested code for login into your project to check if that works. https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-log-in-amp-sign-up

Comment: @CraigGrummitt Thank you for being so helpful and replying so quickly! I just tried what you suggested and copy pasted the code from the Parse link you sent me, and all my console said was "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login." So you're right, the problem isn't in requestFacebook() or returnUserData(). Now I'm not quite sure what to do. Could there maybe be an access token issue or possibly something wrong in my AppDelegate? If there's no other solution, I may try making a new app on parse and linking my project to that instead and see if the issue persists

Comment: I suspect if the generic code from Parse tutorial isn't working, that you're missing a framework, or perhaps you've got a problem in your AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method. Within this method have you run Parse.setApplicationId, and PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions, and are you returning FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application?

Comment: @CraigGrummitt I updated my question with the code from my AppDelegate and screenshots of my frameworks. I believe I have all of the frameworks that the Parse starting guide said I needed, and I have Parse.setApplicationId and PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions, and I have FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance() without the ".application" at the end, although it's not returned. I tried changing it in and it gave an error, but maybe I set it up incorrectly somehow in my code.

Comment: According to facebook docs(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started) at the end of the didLaunchWithOptions method, you should have the line: return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions) Maybe you should try that?

Comment: Also, I assume you replaced your appID and client key with XXX's just for here right? Several other things off the top of my head to check:  Have you added the necessary lines to your info.plist as specified in Facebook getting started? (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started)  Have you made your Facebook app public? If not or are you trying to login via the same account that created the app? Added the facebook app ID to the Parse app setting page?

Comment: @CraigGrummitt I just made the change in your first comment and it gave no compile error, however it still unfortunately says "User cancelled FB login" when I use the app. And yes, I did replace my appID and client key with the X's just for here. I believe I set up the info.plist correctly, but I'll double check just in case. My Facebook app is not public, but I'm logging in via the same account that created the app. And I did add my FB app ID and secret to the Parse app setting page.

Comment: Just a comment... It appears that the new FBSDK is a little buggy. I tried to setup my new App that uses both the Parse and FB SDKs and I had trouble setting it up. You can refer to my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30814366/parse-and-facebook-sdk-imports-conflict-in-xcode-6-parsefacebookutils-is-not . Just a thought, are you importing the Bolts Framework? do you get any errors? please let me know if you solved your issue, maybe it could solve mine as well! Thanks

Comment: @JackGal I tried adding bolts to my app and it made no difference, but I took a look at your question and hopefully my answer helps! Still no solution to my problem though :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, after months of frustration I finally solved the problem! And it was surprisingly simple. I decided to just create a new Xcode project specifically for testing the PFFacebookUtils login to see if I could create a login system that didn't have this issue. Sure enough, after carefully following Parse's Facebook Login guide (https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-facebook-users), I successfully logged in through PFFacebookUtils with no issue on the test app! It turns out I had all of my frameworks set up correctly, but there was a mix of unnecessary code and slightly different syntax for certain key functions in my app that caused the cancel login issue. I will put all of the code from my PFFacebookUtils test project below so anyone facing the same issue can edit their code to match it. If that doesn't work, I would recommend trying it out yourself and seeing where they differ.

AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Parse

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    //X's replace my actual Parse information

    Parse.setApplicationId("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", clientKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
    PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)

    PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)

    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {

    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}

/*
func application(application: UIApplication, url: NSURL, sourceApplication: NSString, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {

    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
        application,
        openURL: url,
        sourceApplication: sourceApplication as String,
        annotation: annotation)

}*/

func application(application: UIApplication,
    openURL url: NSURL,
    sourceApplication: String?,
    annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,
            openURL: url,
            sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
            annotation: annotation)
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    self.saveContext()
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

let permissions = [ "email","user_birthday", "public_profile", "user_friends"]

@IBAction func loginButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions) {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let user = user {
            if user.isNew {
                println("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
            } else {
                println("User logged in through Facebook!")
            }
        } else {
            println("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
        }
    }
}

}
```

The @IBAction is for a simple UIButton I put in the center of the blank viewcontroller in my Main.storyboard

Objective-C Bridging Header:

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
```

Hope this helps anyone else who faces this issue!

Answer (score 0):

**I have 2 advices in this case:**

> 1-) PFUser.enableRevocableSessionInBackground() to create new valid
>   session and try again
>
> 2-) Delete the app in simulator and build again sometimes it makes
>   invalid session issues

Comment: I just tried this method and it made no difference, it still says "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login." I think the issue is in either the requestFacebook() funciton or the returnUserData() function

Comment: i edited my answer i seems you need to get permission on login

Comment: At the very top of my code you can see that I already created a permissions array

Comment: instead of logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions, try to login with logInWithPermissions method in my edited message

Comment: logInWithPermissions was replaced by logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions since Parse version 1.7.2, so that sadly doesn't work

Comment: I checked my AppDelegate and I already placed PFUser.enableRevocableSessionInBackground() in my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method. And I deleted the app in the simulator (and cleaned it) and the problem is still there. :( Any other ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

BSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"email",@"user_location",@"user_birthday",@"user_hometown",@"user_friends"]
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
  completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

```
  switch (state) {
      case FBSessionStateOpen:{


          NSString *link=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.apple.com"];



          NSString *str_img = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://get-groupy.com/images/logo.png"];

          NSDictionary *params = @{
                                   @"name" :[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Get Groupy App"],
                                   @"caption" : @"Download Great App",
                                   @"description" :@"Welcome to iOS world",
                                   @"picture" : str_img,
                                   @"link" : link,
                                   };

          // Invoke the dialog
          [FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                                 parameters:params
                                                    handler:
           ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
               if (error) {

                   //NSLog(@"Error publishing story.");
                   [activityView stopAnimating];
               }

               else {

                   if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {


                       [activityView stopAnimating];



                       //NSLog(@"User canceZled story publishing.");
                       // [self.indicator stopAnimating];
                   }
                   else
                   {




                       [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {





                           if (error) {


                               //NSLog(@"error:%@",error);
                               [activityView stopAnimating];
                           }
                           else {



                               //NSLog(@"%@",user);
                               // retrive user's details at here as shown below
                               //NSLog(@"FB user first name:%@",user.first_name);

                               if ([stringEmail isEqualToString:[user objectForKey:@"email"]] || stringEmail == nil  || stringEmail.length == 0) {



                                   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[user valueForKey:@"id"] forKey:@"User_facebookid"];

                                   NSString *username=[[NSString alloc]init];
                                   username =user.name;
                                   username=[username stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];


                                   //NSLog(@"%@",user.name);

                                   selfusername=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",user.username];
                                   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:user.name forKey:@"selfusername"];



                                   //NSLog(@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"selfusername"]);



                                   friendList = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];





                                   [FBRequestConnection startForMyFriendsWithCompletionHandler:
                                    ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *friends, NSError *error)
                                    {
                                        if(!error){
                                            //NSLog(@"results = %@", friends);


                                            friendList=[friends valueForKey:@"data"];

                                            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:friendList forKey:@"allfreind"];

                                            result1 = [[friendList valueForKey:@"id"] componentsJoinedByString:@","];
                                            NSArray *freindname=[friendList valueForKey:@"first_name"];



                                            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:freindname forKey:@"friendname"];

                                            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:result1 forKey:@"fbid"];






                                            NSDictionary *params = @{@"uname" : user.first_name,
                                                                     @"userId" :[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"userID"],
                                                                     @"issocial" :@"Y",
                                                                     @"ph" :[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"phoneno"],
                                                                     @"facebook_id" :[user valueForKey:@"id"],
                                                                     @"uemail" :[user objectForKey:@"email"],
                                                                     @"ucountry" :[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"countrynameupdate"] ,
                                                                     };

                                            //NSLog(@"%@",params);

                                            NSString* HOST_URL = @"http://groupylive.amebasoftware.com/webservice/get_posts/?post_type=post&mtype=register";
                                            HOST_URL= [HOST_URL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                                            AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *operationManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
                                            [operationManager POST:HOST_URL parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
                                             {






                                                 UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Get Groupy"
                                                                                                     message:@"Login succesfull!!"
                                                                                                    delegate:nil
                                                                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                                 [alertView show];


                                                 GroupViewController *groupViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GroupViewController"];
                                                 [self.navigationController pushViewController:groupViewController animated:YES];




                                             }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){

                                                 [activityView stopAnimating];
                                                 UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Get Groupy"
                                                                                                     message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                                                                    delegate:nil
                                                                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                                 //[alertView show];




                                             }];
                                        }
                                    }
                                    ];
                               }

                               else
                               {
                                   self.view.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
                                   [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
                                   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Get Groupy" message:@"Your registered number has already been assigned another facebook account. Please login with already registered account." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                                   [alert show];

                               }
                           }

                       }];









                       //NSLog(@"Story published.");
                       //[self.indicator stopAnimating];
                   }
               }}];



                          break;
      }

      case FBSessionStateClosed:




          break;


      case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:

          self.view.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
          [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
          [activityView stopAnimating];
          break;
      default:


          break;
  }
```

} ] ;

Comment: Could you please reformat this answer so that it's in Swift (not Objective-C) and also provide some more context?